# Display custom field from child page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a custom field I've made with Advanced Custom fields called Suffix after the child page title, I´m really confused of how to accomplish this.

I've pasted the code a friend helped me with below that lists pages and childpages below.

Is it possible to do this?

```
<?php 
  $pageID =  $sub_field_3 = get_sub_field('page_id');
  $page = get_post($pageID);
  echo $page->post_title;
?>

<ul>
  <?php 
      // use wp_list_pages to display parent and all child pages all generations (a tree with parent)

    $parent = $sub_field_3 = get_sub_field('page_id');
    $args=array(
        'child_of' => $parent
    );

    $pages = get_pages($args);  
    if ($pages) {
       $pageids = array();
          foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $pageids[]= $page->ID;
            $suffix = get_field('suffix', $page->ID);  
                }
            $args=array(
                  'title_li' => ' ',
                  'include' => ',' . implode(",", $pageids)
                );

    wp_list_pages($args);
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will you be using the same suffix across the site, or will it differ depending on the page that you are on?

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for ACF? It may take time to read, but if you expect to develop more of the site, it will be worth reading and trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, this is how I got it to work.

Thanks, K.

```
<?php 
    $parent = $sub_field_3 = get_sub_field('page_id');
    $args=array(
    'child_of' => $parent
    );

$pages = get_pages($args);

if($pages): ?>
     <li> 
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($pages as $page): ?>
        <li class="">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID);?>">
            <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
            <?php

            $suffix = get_field('name_suffix', $page->ID);
                 if($name_suffix):
            ?>

            <span class="suffix"><?php echo $name_suffix; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
       </li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
 </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```